# Reading an Object type from a binary file

Tags: classnotfoundexception

So I'm trying to read from a dat file, and store its contents in an ArrayList of type Website (the dat file contains a list of names with URLs to websites as a website object). My question is what do I need to do in order to be able to read from this file? Currently I'm getting a ClassNotFoundException. Here is the code that I have so far:

```
try
{
    web = (Website) mediaReader.readObject();
    webster.add(web);
    mediaReader.close();
} catch(EOFException e)
{
    more = false;
    System.out.println("File successfully read:");
}
```

mediaReader is an ObjectInputStream, webster is an arrayList of type Website, and web is an instance of the website class. If you need to see the website class for any reason, I will be happy to show you the code.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the error you get is because the `ObjectInputStream` found an object that is **not** a `Website` object, or maybe you didn't add the `Serializable` interface to the class `Website`.
If you didn't, do it and then delete the file you're reading and recreate it with a new object

Comment: Well the problem is that the website class is serialized, and I know that all of the objects in the binary file are website objects.

Comment: Have you modified that class maybe..?

Comment: I figured it out. Turns out it wasn't recognizing the file because it was serialized based on the package it was in, and I took the file out of the package.